# Symfony2 / Doctrine: findBy multiple queries that can be NULL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, findby

I've got several url-queries like for example:

```
/page?type=train&category=others&location=germany

/page?type=car&category=others
```

I fetch them and put them in variables that I want to filter my database-requests with.

That's what I tried:

```
$item = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')
        ->findBy(array(
            'type' => $type,
            'category' => $category,
            'location' => $location
          ));
```

But as you can imagine, if one ore more variables are empty, I'm getting no results...

I want to query all items from the database and filter them by the variables, how can I approach this?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Do it via the querybuilder, adding only existing parameters to the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind you don't have to create the findBy-Criteria inside the querybuilder. Instead you could create it just before with php's `array_filter()`, which will delete all null values:

```
$criteria = array_filter(array(
  'type' => 'search_type',
  'category' => null,
  'location' => 'search_location'
));

$item = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')
    ->findBy($criteria);
```